# Factory Girl: Automatically assigning parent objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot

I'm just getting into Factory Girl and I am running into a difficulty that I'm sure should be much easier.  I just couldn't twist the documentation into a working example.

Assume I have the following models:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :league
   has_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :team
end
```

What I want to do is this:

```
team = Factory.build(:team_with_players)
```

and have it build up a bunch of players for me.  I tried this:

```
Factory.define :team_with_players, :class => :team do |t|
   t.sequence {|n| "team-#{n}" }
   t.players {|p| 
       25.times {Factory.build(:player, :team => t)}
   }
end
```

But this fails on the `:team=>t` section, because `t` isn't really a `Team`, it's a `Factory::Proxy::Builder`.  I *have* to have a team assigned to a player.

In some cases I want to build up a `League` and have it do a similar thing, creating multiple teams with multiple players.

What am I missing?

Comment: I just ran into this exact same problem (same error) and looked all around and haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Factory.define :team do |team|
  team.sequence(:caption) {|n| "Team #{n}" }
end

Factory.define :player do |player|
  player.sequence(:name) {|n| "John Doe #{n}" }
  player.team = nil
end

Factory.define :team_with_players, :parent => :team do |team|
  team.after_create { |t| 25.times { Factory.build(:player, :team => t) } }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Factory.define :team_with_players, :class => :team do |t|
  t.sequence { |n| "team-#{n}" }
  t.players do |team| 
    25.times.collect { |n| team.association(:player) }
  end
end
```

Comment: But if the player needs a reference to the team, where do I get that?  In this example, "team" refers to a factory object...

Comment: I have something similar to this: team.association(:player, :team_id => team) seems strange but works for me.

Comment: when I do that it complains:  "Expected Team, but was FactoryGirl::Proxy" or something like that.